# Можно ли проиндексировать базу данных mysql для ускорения поиска с помощью php?

Tags: php, mysql, индексация

Был написан данный поиск по базе данных MySql:

```
if (isset ($_POST['search'])) {
    $connect = connectPDO();
    search($_POST['search'],$connect);
}


function search($search, $mysqli)
{
    if (!empty($search)) {
        $search = htmlspecialchars($search);
        $search = stripslashes($search);
        $search = addslashes($search);
        if (strlen($search) < 4) {
            $text = 'короткий пошуковий запит';
        } elseif (strlen($search) > 50) {
            $text = 'довгий пошуковий запит';
        } else {
            $aDoor = $_POST['checkedValues'];
            if (empty($aDoor) || count($aDoor) === 0) {
                       $sql = "SELECT * FROM infores WHERE  www_ir LIKE :wwwir  OR mithe_znahod LIKE :mithe_znahod  OR datare LIKE :datare  OR owner_ir LIKE :ownerir  OR lang_ir LIKE :langir OR title_classif LIKE :titleclassif  OR region LIKE :region OR  key_words LIKE :keywords OR id_ir LIKE :id_ir OR owners LIKE :owners OR title LIKE :titles ORDER BY CASE
WHEN title LIKE :titles1 THEN 0
WHEN title LIKE :titles2 THEN 1
WHEN title LIKE :titles3 THEN 2
WHEN title LIKE :titles4 THEN 3
ELSE 4 end";

                    for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
                        $sql_array[$i] = true;
                    }



                $sql_array[4] = true;
            } else {
                $N = count($aDoor);
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM infores WHERE id_ir LIKE :id_ir";
                $sql_array[0] = true;
                for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) {
                    switch ($aDoor[$i]) {
                        case 1:
                            $sql = "$sql OR key_words LIKE :keywords";
                            $sql_array[1] = true;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            $sql = "$sql OR datare LIKE :datare";
                            $sql_array[2] = true;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $sql = "$sql OR mithe_znahod LIKE :mithe_znahod";
                            $sql_array[3] = true;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            $sql = "$sql OR title LIKE :titles";
                            $sql_array[4] = true;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            $sql = "$sql OR owner_ir LIKE :ownerir";
                            $sql_array[5] = true;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            $sql = "$sql OR title_classif LIKE :titleclassif";
                            $sql_array[6] = true;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            $sql = "$sql OR owners LIKE :owners";
                            $sql_array[7] = true;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            $sql = "$sql OR region LIKE :region";
                            $sql_array[8] = true;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            $quantity = 10;
            $limit = 5;

            $page = $_POST['page'];
            if (!is_numeric($page)) $page = 1;
            if ($page < 1) $page = 1;
            $mysqli = connectPDO();
            $statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
                if ($sql_array[0] == true)
            $statement->bindParam(':id_ir', $id_ir); $id_ir = "%$search%";
                if ($sql_array[1] == true)
            $statement->bindParam(':keywords', $keywords); $keywords = "%$search%";
                if ($sql_array[2] == true)
            $statement->bindParam(':datare', $datare); $datare = "%$search%";
                if ($sql_array[3] == true)
            $statement->bindParam(':mithe_znahod', $mithe_znahod); $mithe_znahod = "%$search%";
                if ($sql_array[4] == true){
            $statement->bindParam(':titles', $titles); $titles = "%$search%";
            $statement->bindParam(':titles1', $titles1); $titles1 = "$search";
            $statement->bindParam(':titles2', $titles2); $titles2 = "$search %";
            $statement->bindParam(':titles3', $titles3); $titles3 = "$search%";
            $statement->bindParam(':titles4', $titles4); $titles4 = "% $search%";
                    }
                if ($sql_array[5] == true)
            $statement->bindParam(':ownerir', $ownerir); $ownerir = "%$search%";
                if ($sql_array[6] == true)
            $statement->bindParam(':titleclassif', $titleclassif); $titleclassif = "%$search%";
                if ($sql_array[7] == true)
            $statement->bindParam(':owners', $owners); $owners = "%$search%";
                if ($sql_array[8] == true)
            $statement->bindParam(':region', $region); $region = "%$search%";
                if ($sql_array[9] == true)
            $statement->bindParam(':wwwir', $wwwir); $wwwir = "%$search%";
                if ($sql_array[10] == true)
            $statement->bindParam(':mithe_znahod', $mithe_znahod); $mithe_znahod = "%$search%";
                if ($sql_array[11] == true)
            $statement->bindParam(':langir', $langir); $langir = "%$search%";
            $statement->execute();
            $num = $statement->rowCount();



            $pages = $num / $quantity;
            $pages = ceil($pages);

            $pages++;
            if ($page > $pages) $page = 1;
            if (!isset($list)) $list = 0;
            $list = --$page * $quantity;
            $statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql . " " . "LIMIT $quantity OFFSET $list;");
            if ($sql_array[0] == true)
                $statement->bindParam(':id_ir', $id_ir); $id_ir = "%$search%";
            if ($sql_array[1] == true)
                $statement->bindParam(':keywords', $keywords); $keywords = "%$search%";
            if ($sql_array[2] == true)
                $statement->bindParam(':datare', $datare); $datare = "%$search%";
            if ($sql_array[3] == true)
                $statement->bindParam(':mithe_znahod', $mithe_znahod); $mithe_znahod = "%$search%";
            if ($sql_array[4] == true){
                $statement->bindParam(':titles', $titles); $titles = "%$search%";
                $statement->bindParam(':titles1', $titles1); $titles1 = "$search";
                $statement->bindParam(':titles2', $titles2); $titles2 = "$search %";
                $statement->bindParam(':titles3', $titles3); $titles3 = "$search%";
                $statement->bindParam(':titles4', $titles4); $titles4 = "% $search%";
            }
            if ($sql_array[5] == true)
                $statement->bindParam(':ownerir', $ownerir); $ownerir = "%$search%";
            if ($sql_array[6] == true)
                $statement->bindParam(':titleclassif', $titleclassif); $titleclassif = "%$search%";
            if ($sql_array[7] == true)
                $statement->bindParam(':owners', $owners); $owners = "%$search%";
            if ($sql_array[8] == true)
                $statement->bindParam(':region', $region); $region = "%$search%";
            if ($sql_array[9] == true)
                $statement->bindParam(':wwwir', $wwwir); $wwwir = "%$search%";
            if ($sql_array[10] == true)
                $statement->bindParam(':mithe_znahod', $mithe_znahod); $mithe_znahod = "%$search%";
            if ($sql_array[11] == true)
                $statement->bindParam(':langir', $langir); $langir = "%$search%";
            $statement->execute();
            echo '<h3>За вашим запитом знайдено <span style="color:green;">' . $num . '</span> результатів</h3>';
            add_page($page, $limit, $pages);
            if ($statement->rowCount() > 0) {
                while($row = $statement ->fetch()){
                    $text .= '<br><h3><a onclick="povna_infa(' . $row['id_ir']. ');"  target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;">' . $row['title'] . '</a></h3><h4>' . 'Доменне імя: <a href =' . $row['www_ir']. ' target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;">' . $row['www_ir'] . '</a></p><p>' . 'Дата реєстрації: ' . $row['datare'] . '<p><span style="color:green;"> Активний </span></p>' . '</p><p>' . $row['owners'] . '</p></h4><hr>' . "\n";
            }
                $bold = '<span style="color:red;">' . $search . '</span>';
                $text = str_ireplace($search, $bold, $text);
            } else {
                $text = 'По запиту нічого не знайдено.';
            }
        }
    } else {
        $text = 'Задан пустий запит.';
    }
    echo $text;
    add_page($page, $limit, $pages);
}
```

в процессе написания данного скрипта узнал про индексацию баз данных, и возник вопрос можно ли проиндексировать базу данных с помощью php, например который бы индексировал базу данных автоматически по каким то параметрам без вмешательства пользователей, если можно стоит ли?

Comment: Индекс не может использоваться если поисковое выражение like начинается на знак `%`. Поиск по индексу возможен только если точно известно хотя бы начало ключа.

Comment: Кроме того при поиске одновременно может быть использован только один индекс и при наличии в запросе `OR` высока вероятность что подходящего индекса вообще не найдется. Надо в корне пересматривать работу поиска. например использовать полнотекстовый поиск если там преобладает большой текст или возможно делать собственную индексацию, вроде создания словаря и хранения набора id ключевых слов в записи (в отдельной таблице)

Comment: А стоит индексировать или нет это сложный вопрос и зависит исключительно от объема хранимых данных. начните с того что посмотрите сколько времени занимает поиск сейчас, представьте что БД вырастет раз в 10 по сравнению с текущим объемом, приемлемое ли время поиска будет тогда. Если время не устраивает - надо думать о ускорении запроса. а для этого явно понадобится индекс в том или ином виде